# Numba @njit DEBUG

Tags: debugging, windows-subsystem-for-linux, numba, jit, vscode-debugger

I'm using wsl2 with VSCode.  I'm trying to debug number of Numba functions that have @njit.

How do I set the environment variable globally, I did try to use .numba_config.yaml with

DISABLE_JIT = 1
DEBUG = 1

in the directory where I start the vscode but it didn't seem to work

Comment: what if you open an shell in VS Code's integrated terminal and try to print those environment variables? What do you see?

Comment: I don't know much about WSL or VS Code's support for it, but I assume that environment variables you set in your host where you launch VS Code will not magically propagate to the WSL environment you're connecting to. How are you actually doing your debugging? launch.json? integrated terminal without launch.json? Each way has ways you can add environment variables.